# PHP Security: Allow one PHP script to create file in a root-owned location

Tags: php

I need to create a very simple file (one line long) in a directory owned by `root`, but my PHP server is running as `www-data`.

I have full control of the system, and while I want to grant `www-data` to execute this ONE file with full permission, I don't want to give it access to run anything ELSE as root.

Is there a place where I can grant PHP or the `www-data` user permission to run **just that one file** so that it can create files in the `root`-owned location?

Answer (score 0):

will the filename change?
create the file via the command line and `chown` it to www-data, or www-data's group.
As long as the script doesn't delete the file..  it can't rewrite it and do with it as it pleases.

Comment: No, the filename doesn't need to change, but I think you misunderstood: the file **is already** created by and owned as `www-data` and needs to be moved to a `root` owned directory.

Comment: so... move the file to where you want it via the command line....  if the user/group has write permissions on the file, they can write to the file.. even if they don't have directory write permissions.   http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work

Comment: I'm looking to automate this.  So a PHP script creates a file either in the `root`-owned directory (or creates it then immediately moves it there).  The only way I could move it via the command line is if I use the `mv` command, but that needs permission.  Hence the question :-\

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling you are trying to obtain root permissions for some specific process through the execution of the one file. In any case here is a solution.

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code.

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('php /path/to/your/script');
```